# Take a few minutes of your math class

Tags: word-usage

Our class had been practicing for an upcoming play.(They aren't  practicing at the moment because they're studying Math). Our Math teacher was teaching us, when the teacher who was in charge of the play showed up. She said:

> **Can I take a few minutes of your (math) class?** These kids have to practice for their upcoming play.

By "class" I don't mean the group of students in the classroom at the moment"  but I mean "Math class".

Is the use of "take a few minutes of your class" natural? If not, then what will be a natural way to express it?

Answer (score 1):

This does sound natural.

- It's understood that **"class"** means "math class" (*a period of time*), because it's right after "minutes of".  "Minutes of `xx`" needs `xx` to be a period of time.
- This use of the word "**take**" comes from the well-known phrases:

> - Take your time.
>     (*Take as much time as you need*).
>
> See Definition: [Idioms by the Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+up+time#Definition); [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/take-your-time)
>
> - Take up someone's time.
>     (*Use someone else's time*).
>
> To "take up" something can mean **to use it**, so you use time, especially if it's time that belongs to someone else.    (Definition: [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+up+time), [Phrasemix](https://www.phrasemix.com/examples/listen-i-dont-want-to-take-up-too-much-of-your-time))

In this case, the time "belongs" to the math teacher, and the drama teacher is "taking it" (seizing it), and will "take it up" (use it).